# Merging four new line delimited json files using jq

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to merge 4 JSON files (in the future maybe two more).
The only common factor between the newline delimited JSON files is "vulnid".

```
File 1: 
{"vulnid":"cve1", "product":"product1"}
{"vulnid":"cve2", "product":"product2"}
{"vulnid":"cve3", "product":"product3"}
{"vulnid":"cve4", "product":""}
{"vulnid":"cve5", "product":""}
{"vulnid":"cve6", "product":""}

File 2: 
{"vulnid":"cve1", "version":"version1"}
{"vulnid":"cve2", "version":"version2"}
{"vulnid":"cve3", "version":"version3"}
{"vulnid":"cve4", "version":"version4"}

File 3: 
{"vulnid":"cve1", "patch":"patch1"}
{"vulnid":"cve2", "patch":"patch2"}
{"vulnid":"cve3", "patch":"patch3"}
{"vulnid":"cve4", "patch":""}

File 4: 
{"vulnid":"cve1", "speed":"speed1"}
{"vulnid":"cve2", "power":"power2"}
{"vulnid":"cve3", "amps":"amps3"}
{"vulnid":"cve4", "product":"product4"}
{"vulnid":"cve4", "patch":"patch4"}


Required output:
{"vulnid":"cve1", "product":"product1", "version":"version1", "patch":"patch1", "speed":"speed1"}
{"vulnid":"cve2", "product":"product2", "version":"version2", "patch":"patch2", "power":"power2"}
{"vulnid":"cve3", "product":"product3", "version":"version3", "patch":"patch3", "amps":"amps3"}
{"vulnid":"cve4", "product":"product4", "version":"version4", "patch":"patch4"}
{"vulnid":"cve5", "product":""}
{"vulnid":"cve6", "product":""}
```

What I have tried so far:

```
jq -s '.[0] * .[1] * .[3] * .[4]' json1 json2 json3 json4
jq -s '.[0] + .[1] + .[3] + .[4]' json1 json2 json3 json4
```

... and multiple different combinations of jq, all of them provided incorrect results and proved the point that I am not understand the tool.

Is this even possible to accomplish such merging using the field "vulnid" with jq?

Answer (score 3):

The shortest **`jq`** solution:

```
jq -sc 'group_by(.vulnid)[] | add' file*.json
```

The output:

```
{"vulnid":"cve1","product":"product1","version":"version1","patch":"patch1","speed":"speed1"}
{"vulnid":"cve2","product":"product2","version":"version2","patch":"patch2","power":"power2"}
{"vulnid":"cve3","product":"product3","version":"version3","patch":"patch3","amps":"amps3"}
{"vulnid":"cve4","product":"product4","version":"version4","patch":"patch4"}
{"vulnid":"cve5","product":""}
{"vulnid":"cve6","product":""}
```

Comment: ah, I just couldn't wrap my head around `group_by`, but that does make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I think so.

If we change the data so that we have the `vulnid` strings as keys, with the object itself as the corresponding value (e.g. `{"cve1": {"vulnid": "cve1", "product": "product1" }}`), then we can use `reduce` and `*` to combine the ones with the same keys. The first `map()` below produces the correct format for the `reduce`.

So, with your sample input in the file `json`:

```
$ < json jq -s 'map({(.vulnid): . }) | reduce .[] as $item ({}; . * $item) '
{
  "cve1": {
    "vulnid": "cve1",
    "product": "product1",
    "version": "version1",
    "patch": "patch1",
    "speed": "speed1"
  },
  ...
```

Then it's rather simple to drop the fluff around the objects to get the expected output:

```
$ < json jq -s 'map({(.vulnid): . }) | 
                    reduce .[] as $item ({}; . * $item) | map(.) | .[]'
{
  "vulnid": "cve1",
  "product": "product1",
  "version": "version1",
  "patch": "patch1",
  "speed": "speed1"
}
...
```

I wouldn't be surprised if there was a better way to do all of this, though.

Comment: @Anna, uhh, comments don't work too well for formatted text, but if I got that right, I think you changed the input to `{"cve1": {...}}` manually. The first `map(...)` in my script was there to do just that, and doing it again doesn't work (since the new objects don't have the `vulnid` key). I meant to just push the sample data in your question to the command as-is (without the `File N` headers, of course).

Comment: I am sorry, worked! I don't have to parse as you suggested because the jq does that! :) Amazing, thanks!